# authentication of user using nodejs+express+passport local strategy and new angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express, passport.js

I have followed every blog which describe how to use local strategy with passport running on express. the users data sits on mysql, and i have created the server code

```
let express = require('express')
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let path = require('path');
let app = express()
let cors = require('cors');
let passport = require('passport');
let flash = require('connect-flash');

let morgan = require('morgan');
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let session = require('express-session');


app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console

app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-
   With, Content-Type, Accept");
   next();
});



app.use(cors());
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({
   secret: 'secretme',
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: true
})); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in 
      session

require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for 
       configuration

function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {

    //if (req.user && req.user.authenticated)
    //    return next();
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    res.status(401).send()
}

app.get('/api/about', isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        version: '1.1'
    })
})
```

the login pass ok, this is the function:

```
 app.post('/api/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
failureRedirect: '/bad-login',
failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
}), (req, res) => {
     res.status(200).send();
})
```

regarding the client side, I am using Angular v4 , the login call pass ok

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  let options = new RequestOptions({
    headers: headers
  })
  let data = new URLSearchParams();
  data.append('email', email);
  data.append('password', password);
  let body = data.toString()
  return  this._http.post(`http://X.X.X.X/api/login`, body, options)
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => response.status)
}
```

how ever when I call the about api , I am getting 401. What did i missed?

```
about(): Promise<About> {
    return this._http.get(`http://X.X.X.X/api/about`, { withCredentials: true })
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json() as About)
}
```

the code for the login:

```
let LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
let bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
let Users = require('../user');

module.exports = passport => {

// used to serialize the user for the session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.email);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    let userDao = new Users();
    userDao.getUser(id).then(user => {
        done(undefined, user);
    })

});

passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form
        let userDao = new Users();
        userDao.getUser(email)
            .then(users => {
                if (!users.length) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.'));
                }
                let user = users[0];
                if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.'));
                }


                return done(null, user);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(`got error in login: ${err}`)
            })


    }));
 }
```

Comment: Please include your code which actually performs the `local-login` step with Passport. Also, what is status of the response on the client side after logging in (`console.log(response.status)` on the last line of that snippet)?

Comment: the client gets 200